# Why am I seeing output during 'rake test' other than '.' 'F' or 'E' (ruby 1.9.2p290, Rails 3.0.9)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rake

When I used to run 'rake test' I would see either '.' or 'F' or 'E' for each test.
When all was well, the output was a line of '.'

Now, even though all my test are passing, I am seeing program output in the midst of the line of '.'

I am not sure the best way to post the output, but here is an initial offering:

```
perrys-MacBook-Pro:iway perry_mac$ rake test:functionals --trace
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:functionals
Loaded suite /Users/perry_mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.........................."Welcome joe : "
."Welcome joe : "
."Welcome joe : "
."Welcome joe : "
.................."Welcome bob : "
...........
Finished in 0.998462 seconds.

58 tests, 81 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 15796
```

The line of code generating the output is:
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
  <div id="nav">
      <% if current_user %>
            <% str= "Welcome " + current_user.username + " : "%>
            <%= p str %>
      <%= link_to "Edit Profile : ", edit_user_path(current_user.id)%>
      <%= link_to "Logout", :logout%>
      <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Register", new_user_path%> |
      <%= link_to "Login", :login %>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

The "Welcome joe : " and "Welcome bob : " msgs are expected program output seen after a user successfully logs in.  bob and joe are usernames created in a fixtures file.  I can't figure out why the msgs are now seen during 'rake test'  I see the same behavior when --trace is not used as well.  Please comment on A) why I see some program output and not the rest and B) Why am I seeing any at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grep for **"puts"** or other code that writes to **stdout** in your app or test code.  Something is leaking data to stdout.

It looks like your view template is sending the content to stdout as well as the view:

```
    <%= p str %>
```

The p function sends the string to stdout and then returns the string.  The <%= ERB directive injects the value into the page being rendered, so you were both printing it out to stdout/console and rendering it in the page.  This caused it to appear on the console when you were running tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I never used to see this unexpected output, and now I do.  I have not changed <%= p str %> for some time.  I don't know why this particular line suddenly started doing what it's doing.  I just tried switching 'p' with 'puts' and see the same weird thing.

Comment: Hmmm... I just grepped for 'puts' in my application code and this is the only place I am using puts.  Huh.  Still, this line never piped output to the screen during rake test before.  Why now?

Comment: Isn't this how (p and puts) should be used?  I have no clue why their output started appearing during 'rake test.'  If I comment out the line, then no msg appears during rake test, but I also get no msg during 'runtime.'  More than anything, I want to know more about rake test and I have developed a low tolerance for not grasping quirks like this one.  I am hoping this generates a learning moment at some point.

Comment: You don't need the `p` when rendering a value in a template -- just wrap the expression in erb tags, e.g. <%= str %>

Comment: Thanks for your comment zetetic.  Yes, I did this.  It removes the ?unexpected output.  Still, I was using <%= p str %> and did not see str output during 'rake test'  Don't know why I started to.  Maybe there is a flag for directing output that I somehow changed?  Anyways, thanks for your help.